# vba excel: Breaking into vba code when a message box is caught in infinite loop

Tags: excel, vba

This can be a very valuable if there is an answer to it:

You have a messagebox within a loop, and you can't break into the code because the Messagbox keeps popping up.
Once the Messagebox is up, you can't really go back to the vba developement window to stop the program, because it is a modal window that takes over then entire vba.

Any good way to break into this?  I don't want to go through a loop of 10000 items.  I've seen enough, so I am ready to break into the code--to stop the code from running further.

How do I do this gracefully, without losing possibly any edits I may have made?

Maybe this can't be done, but worth knowing if it is possible.

Comment: Try hammering `Esc`. In future build your `MsgBox`s better. Compile the message that you want and then display in one box

Comment: this is a good reason to save all changes before running any code.  Then you could just shut it down and reopen.

Comment: also Ctrl & Break

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> to break into the code even when a MessageBox is being displayed.

Comment: It does work, but if the loop has been running for a while, it seems not to work. it might be okay in your situation as the msgbox will not let the loop go wild.

Answer (score 0):

if i interpret correctly your need :

"I don't want to go through a loop of 10000 items. I've seen enough, so I am ready to break into the code--to stop the code from running further."

Instead of a msgbox, you could use

```
Debug.print InformationYouNeed
stop
```

Then read the result and stop the code if you got the info you needed.

Can you provide the code you're using ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set breakpoint on `MsgBox` line.

In order to do that just press F9, when you have cursor on that line.

Then the execution will stop before showing message box and you'll be able to inspect all variables as well as stop the code.

After setting breakpoint, the line wil l be highlighted with dark red:
[image]

(insted of using F9 you can just click in place of the red circle - this will also set a brakpoint)

Other way is to show messagebox using WinApi, as descirbed [here](https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4699). But it's more complicated than using breakpoints. Code snippet for 64-bit windows:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBox _
        Lib "User32" Alias "MessageBoxA" _
           (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
            ByVal lpText As String, _
            ByVal lpCaption As String, _
            ByVal wType As Long) _
        As Long

Sub MsgBoxTests()
    ' Execution will show message box and stop on this line,
    ' at this point you will be able to stop execution, but still, you
    ' will need to dismiss messagebox
    MessageBox &O0, "This is a native Message Box", "My Box", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```